# highcharts different tick interval

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcharts to graph some datas. I can select two dates and the graph will show the datas between those 2 dates.

I have the following code:

```
options.xAxis[0] = {
    type: 'datetime',
    tickInterval: 3600 * 1000, // one hour
    tickWidth: 5,
    gridLineWidth: '1',
    gridLineColor: gridLineColor,
    labels: {
        align: 'center',
        x: -3,
        y: 20,
        formatter: function() {
            return '<b style=\"font-size:120%\">' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%d-%m', this.value) + '<b>' + '<br>'  + Highcharts.dateFormat('%l%p', this.value);
        }
    },
    opposite: false
}
```

My problem is that if I have 1 day, I see all the hours and if I have selected 5 days for example, I see the 5 days on the axis but if I select 3 months, I see all the days within those 3 months. And this is unreadable.

Is it possible to say that you don't want to have more than 10 intervals shown on the axis?

Many thanks,

John.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. Set your tickInterval dynamically. Set the interval depending on time frame of your data
2. use the tickPixlInterval option. This decides on logical tick intervals that fall somewhere close to the pixel value you specify.

   - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPixelInterval